# python import ignoring local package

Tags: python, python-2.x

**Note that doing this is not a good idea. It's confusing, error-prone, and typically completely unnecessary.**

But for the sake of argument, say you have a local package that with the same name as a global package:

```
module/
   __init__.py
   os.py
   thisfile.py
```

inside `thisfile.py`, you could explicitly specify that you wanted to import your *local* version of `os.py` using one of the following:

```
from . import os
from .os import foo
```

But in fact, with python 2.x, local package resolution is the default. Just a simple `import os` would load the local `os.py` instead of the system package.

So how do I, inside `thisfile.py` import the system-level `os` package instead of the locally-defined alternative?

Comment: While there are ways to deal with this, as mata's answer and [PEP 328](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/) explain, it's really not a good idea to give your modules the same name as a stdlib module in the first place. Even if you can avoid confusing the interpreter, you'll still confuse every human reader of your code.

Comment: @abarnert Agreed. Now see the first 8 words of the question.

Comment: I was just pointing out _why_ it's not a good idea, because I think the comment will be useful to future readers who search for this, see nothing more than "Ignoring for a moment whether this is sensible…", and think they ought to actually do this rather than keep things simple.

Comment: @abarnert good point; i'll make that more explicit in the question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This behaviour is python2 specific. In python3, imports are absolute by default to fix exactly this kind of problem.

In python2.5+<sup>*</sup>, you can fix this behaviour using a future import:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
```

After that, all imports will be absolute and to import a module which has the same name as a top level module you *have* to use the explicit relative import syntax.

See [PEP 328](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/) for further background.

---

<sup>*</sup>edit: in earlier python versions, the only option would be to modify `sys.path` in a way that the top level module is found first - which is actually a terrible solution.

Answer (score 1):

You have it the other way around.

```
# Absolute import
import os

# Relative import
from . import os
```

Docs: http://docs.python.org/2/whatsnew/2.5.html#pep-328-absolute-and-relative-imports

In older Python (everything below 3.0) versions you have to enable it manually though, here is a list with all the [`__future__` features](http://docs.python.org/2/library/__future__.html?highlight=absolute)

For Python 2.5-2.x:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
```

Comment: Edited question to reflect that this is about the python 2.x default behavior